# Standalone and Coffins

Tags: standalone, subfiles, xcoffins

I would like to compile a XeTeX file that pulls in multiple files that have coffins defined for their page geometry.

All files compile on their own, and when I run them together, the coffin pages don't display in the final compilation. I have tried using the subfile package, but I found that my coffin files would not compile.

Also, I put everything in the MWE for the two coffin files so that we can troubleshoot things that might harm the file displaying.

Main TeX MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx, amsmath, xcolor, wrapfig, float, subfiles, enumitem, xcoffins, atbegshi, fontspec}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\setmainfont{Futura}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\Large\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
   \markright{\thechapter\ #1}}

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\definecolor{BLUE}{HTML}{23afdc}
\definecolor{RED}{HTML}{a81e2d}
\definecolor{ORANGE}{HTML}{ea6d3c}
\definecolor{YELLOW}{HTML}{e6a327}
\definecolor{GREEN}{HTML}{5fa244}
\definecolor{INDIGO}{HTML}{005988}
\definecolor{VIOLET}{HTML}{7B2C8E}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

Basic Text imported from a basic text file goes here.

\import{level3/hymns}{I.Fireyes}

\import{level3/hymns}{II.Meatwar}


\end{document}
```

I.Fireyes File:

```
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}   
\documentclass[class=article, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{ifthen,changepage}
\usepackage{nopageno} % supress page number

%\usepackage[papersize={8in,8in}, top=1in, textwidth=6in, marginratio=1:1 ]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%  shipout even and odd pages title and figures
            \checkoddpage
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{oddpage}}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameOx}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameEx}}
    }

\NewCoffin\FrameOx
\NewCoffin\FrameOddx
\NewCoffin\FigTT
\NewCoffin\FigBT
\NewCoffin\FigRT
\NewCoffin\FigRM
\NewCoffin\FigLB
\NewCoffin\FigM
%\NewCoffin\FigM
%\NewCoffin\FigR

\NewCoffin\FrameEx
\NewCoffin\FrameEvenx

%%%%%%%%%   set figures width/height  plus height of text area
\newlength{\imageRT}
\setlength{\imageRT}{1in} % height and width of the figures, max =2in <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\imageRM}
\setlength{\imageRM}{1.05in}
\newlength{\imageLB}
\setlength{\imageLB}{2.5in}
\newlength{\textsty}
\setlength{\textsty}{2.9in}

\newlength{\textH}
\setlength{\textH}{6in} % height of text area, min =3\imageW  <<<<<<<<<<<<
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%\newgeometry{papersize={7.5in,7.5in}, textwidth=4in, marginratio=1:1}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameOddx{\textH}{\color{white}\rule{\textH}{\textH}}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigRT{\imageRT}{% top right
    \includegraphics[height=\imageRT,width=\imageRT]{1aries}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigRM{3in}{% middle right
    \includegraphics[height=\imageRM,width=3in]{3-1}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigLB{\imageLB}{% leftmost bottom
    \includegraphics[height=\imageLB,width=\imageLB]{01}

\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{center}
        \textit{Full of light; Reveal the way.}
\end{center}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigTT{\textsty}{
{\huge I. Fireyes}

\vspace{0.25cm}

{\scriptsize\textbf{Mercenarium Function:} When you sing I. Fireyes, you may choose and discard any number of cards from your hand (you do not have to discard any if you do not wish to). After this, draw cards from the deck until you are holding the maximum of (5) non-hymn cards.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize If this hymn causes a player to draw the last card in the deck before they are holding (5) non-hymn cards, the game enters singularity (meaning that the deck, hymnal, and discard pile are shuffled together, see \textcolor{red}{“Singularity” p. xx}) and the player then continues to draw from the singularity deck until they are holding 5 cards. After singing this hymn, discard it.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize If the game enters singularity for any other reason, the effect of I. Fireyes becomes “Draw (5) cards.”}

\vspace{-0.09cm}

%\vfill
\rule{\textsty}{0.1pt}
%\vfill
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigBT{\textsty}{
\rule{\textsty}{0.1pt}

\vfill

{\scriptsize\textbf{Dragonfruit Meanings:}
\textbf{Authority} / Charge, Attraction, Influence / Patience}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize Fireyes represents the gathering of energy before great movement; the act of preparation, of planning, or of cultivating the skills and resources needed to affect meaningful change in the world. It represents leadership and asks us to reflect on the true nature of power; as well as the responsibility of action that comes to those who have cultivated themselves (to have authority is to have both power and duty). It describes the tendency for power to accumulate: As resources and respect build, so too the creative capacities of its sovereignty. Its alteration suggests that the way to cultivate authority is through patience – though taking the time to wait, to learn, and to listen.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize \textbf{Aces} are \textbf{LEADERS}: “The Adept” archetype; Individuals with material power and sources of inspiration or resentment in those around them. Their influence allows them to affect the world in good and bad ways even through small actions. Their powers are amplified by technology, represented in their illustrations as legendary artifacts.}

}

%%%%%%********************* assembly of odd pages

\JoinCoffins\FrameOddx[r,t]\FigRT[r,t]% top right
\JoinCoffins\FrameOddx[l,t]\FigTT[l,t]% top text
\JoinCoffins\FrameOddx[r,b]\FigBT[r,b]% bottom right
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[r,t]\FigRM[r,t](0pt,-\imageRT-0.27in) %Vgap here
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[l,b]\FigLB[l,b] %bottom row

\JoinCoffins*\FrameOx[l,t]\FrameOddx[l,t]

%%%%************************
   
\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameEvenx{\textwidth}{\color{white}\rule{\textwidth}{\textH}}

\newlength{\Hoffset}
\setlength{\Hoffset}{\oddsidemargin}

% *************** even pages
%\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenx[hc, t]\Lyricx[hc,b](0pt,\baselineskip)
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEx[hc,vc]\FrameEvenx[l,t](\Hoffset,-\baselineskip)   
%*********************************************  
    
\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\clearpage

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}

\textit{Foreign melodies, who is telling these}\\
\textit{animated, complicated fugues?}\\
\textit{Form a symphony, out of your sympathies,}\\
\textit{if you'd please tell us what we should do.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{Hidden in the deepest forest,}\\
\textit{there's a quiet, constant chorus,}\\
\textit{led by men, with eyes, of fire.}\\
\textit{Their chanting's only getting stronger;}\\
\textit{they'll all burn if they're much longer;}\\
\textit{cast into, the funeral pyre.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{Animosity is unbecoming,}\\
\textit{overwhelmed as you may feel.}\\
\textit{Color crossed with destiny,}\\
\textit{you'll be satisfied with what the light reveals.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{Hidden in the deepest forest,}\\
\textit{there's a quiet, constant chorus}\\
\textit{led by men with eyes of fire,}\\
\textit{as they ignite that funeral pyre.}\\
\textit{Their chanting's only getting stronger.}\\
\textit{They'll all burn if they're much longer,}\\
\textit{but they afford their apathy to}\\
\textit{the fire in their eyes.}\\
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

II.Meatwar File:

```
\documentclass[class=article, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}   
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{ifthen,changepage}
\usepackage{nopageno} % supress page number

%\usepackage[papersize={8in,8in}, top=1in, textwidth=6in, marginratio=1:1 ]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%  shipout even and odd pages title and figures
            \checkoddpage
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{oddpage}}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameOMeatx}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameEMeatx}}
    }

\NewCoffin\FrameOMeatx
\NewCoffin\FrameOddMeatx
\NewCoffin\FigMeatTT
\NewCoffin\FigMeatBT
\NewCoffin\FigMeatRT
\NewCoffin\FigMeatRM
\NewCoffin\FigMeatLB
\NewCoffin\FigMeatM
%\NewCoffin\FigM
%\NewCoffin\FigR

\NewCoffin\FrameEMeatx
\NewCoffin\FrameEvenMeatx

%%%%%%%%%   set figures width/height  plus height of text area
\newlength{\imageMeatRT}
\setlength{\imageMeatRT}{1in} % height and width of the figures, max =2in <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\imageMeatRM}
\setlength{\imageMeatRM}{1.06285in}
\newlength{\imageMeatLB}
\setlength{\imageMeatLB}{2.5in}
\newlength{\textstyMeat}
\setlength{\textstyMeat}{2.9in}

\newlength{\textHMeat}
\setlength{\textHMeat}{6in} % height of text area, min =3\imageW  <<<<<<<<<<<<
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameOddMeatx{\textHMeat}{\color{white}\rule{\textHMeat}{\textHMeat}}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigMeatRT{\imageMeatRT}{% top right
    \includegraphics[height=\imageMeatRT,width=\imageMeatRT]{2taurus}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigMeatRM{3in}{% middle right
    \includegraphics[height=\imageMeatRM,width=2.9in]{3-2}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigMeatLB{\imageMeatLB}{% leftmost bottom
    \includegraphics[height=\imageMeatLB,width=\imageMeatLB]{02}

\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{center}
        \textit{Guardian's gaze; Pay the price.}
\end{center}
}

%\SetVerticalCoffin\FigM{\textwidth}{\rule{2\textwidth}{.1pt}}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigMeatTT{\textstyMeat}{
\sffamily{\huge II. Meatwar}

\vspace{0.25cm}

{\scriptsize\textbf{Mercenarium Function:} II. Meatwar is sung in reaction to an enemy player’s turn action: If you hold II. Meatwar when any other player moves to capture a card, you may immediately reveal II. Meatwar, discard it, and cause both cards involved in said capture to be annihilated. This applies to any capture interaction, including those involving 0. The Fool or 00. The Fox. If an enemy player uses V. Dragoon to attempt (2) consecutive captures, the player holding II. Meatwar may choose to reveal it after the first or the second capture. The player that reveals and sings this hymn must pass their next turn.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize A player may attempt to sing XIII. Zodiac as II. Meatwar in reaction to another player’s capture, but only if they can roll the appropriate number on the Zodiac die. See “Meatwar Special” under the hymnal entry for XIII. Zodiac for more information.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

%\vfill
\rule{\textstyMeat}{0.1pt}
%\vfill
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigMeatBT{\textstyMeat}{

\rule{\textstyMeat}{0.1pt}

\vfill

{\scriptsize\textbf{Dragonfruit Meanings:}
\textbf{Sacrifice} / Ritual, Suffering, Exchange / Abundance}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize Meatwar represents the cycle of work and harvest; toil undertaken willingly or with awareness, so that a goal can be reached, or a need satisfied. It can also represent necessary social conflict that must be sought out and resolved for growth to take place. It alludes to a voluntary destruction or release of one reality to produce the conditions for another to arise; or else, a change in our focus that allows something to fall away so that something more urgent can be cultivated. It suggests an intentional nature to this sacrifice; that the person making the sacrifice is aware of what they are losing and what they hope to receive by doing so. Its alteration suggests the prosperity attained by those willing to suffer in search of it.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\scriptsize 2s are \textbf{SACRIFICES}: acts of giving something up (time, money, pride, family) to gain something in return.}

}

%%%%%%********************* assembly of odd pages

\JoinCoffins\FrameOddMeatx[r,t]\FigMeatRT[r,t]% top right
\JoinCoffins\FrameOddMeatx[l,t]\FigMeatTT[l,t]% top text
\JoinCoffins\FrameOddMeatx[r,b]\FigMeatBT[r,b]% bottom right
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddMeatx[r,t]\FigMeatRM[r,t](0.1in,-\imageMeatRT-0.49in) %Vgap here
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddMeatx[l,b]\FigMeatLB[l,b](0.25in,0pt) %bottom row

\JoinCoffins*\FrameOMeatx[l,t]\FrameOddMeatx[l,t]

%%%%************************
   
\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameEvenMeatx{\textwidth}{\color{white}\rule{\textwidth}{\textHMeat}}

\newlength{\HoffsetMeat}
\setlength{\HoffsetMeat}{\oddsidemargin}

% *************** even pages
%\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenx[hc, t]\Lyricx[hc,b](0pt,\baselineskip)
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEMeatx[hc,vc]\FrameEvenMeatx[l,t](\HoffsetMeat,-\baselineskip)   
%*********************************************  
    
\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\clearpage

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}

\textit{There's blood to lose.}\\
\textit{Come through.}\\
\textit{Food, is it you?}\\
\textit{You'll save yourself,}\\
\textit{and I will too.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{I don't want the same runes}\\
\textit{that have seemed to fail you;}\\
\textit{all the crimson tales whose}\\
\textit{souls raise hell do.}\\
\textit{There's an ample pain, down,}\\
\textit{looking past your eyes}\\
\textit{where all the anger is.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{It's a Meat War!}\\
\textit{I feel it too,}\\
\textit{and I'm sort of sorry}\\
\textit{this happened to you.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{I'm ready for ascent.}\\
\textit{For the courageous,}\\
\textit{there is no medicine,}\\
\textit{no medicine.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{There's no medicine.}\\
\textit{For courageous men,}\\
\textit{there is no medicine.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{It's a meatwar,}\\
\textit{It's a meatwar.}
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are able to compile the two subfiles, the easier way to incorporate the two pdf files in the main document is using `pdfpages`.

```
... previous preamble
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    
\mainmatter
    
Basic Text imported from a basic text file goes here.
    
%   \import{level3/hymns}{I.Fireyes}
%   
%   \import{level3/hymns}{II.Meatwar}

\includepdf[pages=-]{I.Fireyes.pdf}

\includepdf[pages=-]{II.Meatwar.pdf}    
    
\end{document}
```

[image: fly]

Remember that you can displace the coffins with offsets. For example en the second file

```
 \JoinCoffins*\FrameOddMeatx[l,b]\FigMeatLB[l,b](0.25in,-15pt) %bottom row
```

works better than adding `vspace` inside the frame collector,

Using the same `geometry` setup in the three files the result looks better.

```
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

[image: outb]

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for, though my pdfs come in scaled down. Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: Because you have the geometry set up commented in the two files. Add  in both `\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}`, that is use the same layout of the page in the three files.